# Graphical corruption after suspending and waking up with nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

On waking up from suspend, my machine starts suffering severe graphical corruption. My desktop background seems to be complete random noise, though it is static, and some programs' close and minimize icons are completely gone. I got an NVIDIA GTX 960M, and I'm currently using nvidia-378 drivers, though nvidia-375 drivers don't solve the problem. My machine is running Ubuntu 17.04 development. [image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue.